# How to write a property handler for Windows Search integration on Windows 7 in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi

I want to create a property handler for my application's file format. I only need it to work in Windows 7. I know that I need to build it in both 32-bit and 64-bit for the different editions of Windows, so no need to remind me of that, although for now I'm stuck with Delphi 2007. I just need pointing in the right direction to get started. Which type of project should I create, and what other steps are mandatory to make this work?

Comment: You need to upgrade to XE2 for a start. That's what gets you 64 bit support. Myself, I would probably do it in C++ with Visual Studio. I suspect you will find example code for C++ but not for Delphi.

Comment: Thanks. I realise that I need to upgrade to XE2 to build in 64-bit, but I can't just yet. I don't know C++ at all.

Comment: If your able to purchase a component set http://www.shellplus.com/ looks promising.  They have a page dedicated to developing a property handler with their toolset, as well: http://www.shellplus.com/examples/property-sheet/property-sheet-example.html

Comment: @SilentD Property sheet is different from a property handler. A property handler is what allows you to integrate you file format into Windows search. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266532(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @matthewk: Revise your requirement. Maybe someone can port to Delphi (2007) [taglibhandler](http://taglibhandler.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/taglibhandler/trunk/taglibhandler/) from Sourceforge or IdealPropertyHandler sample from MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

Create an `ActiveX Library` project (File > New > Other > Delphi Projects > ActiveX > ActiveX Library), which will generate a DLL project with a default Type Library.  With that project open, add a COM object to it (File > New > Other > Delphi Projects > ActiveX > COM Object).  Name it whatever you want.  In the generated implementation code, add whatever additional COM interfaces you need to the generated class, and implement their methods as needed.  Compile, then register the DLL using Windows' command-line `regsvr32.exe` utility.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great start. Does it matter which options I choose for "Instancing" and "Threading Model"? Should I tick "Include Type Library" and/or "Mark interface Oleautomation"? Which additional COM interfaces do I need to add to the generated class?

Comment: Shell extensions should be "Apartment" threaded and "Multi" instanced. You don't need "Mark interface Oleautomation" or "Include Type Library", but they don't hurt. Read the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144125.aspx) about which interfaces you need to implement. For a Property Handler, you need to implement either the `IPropertyStore` or `IFilter` interface, optionally the `IPropertyStoreCapabilities` interface, and one or more of the `IInitializeWithStream`, `IInitializeWithFile`, or `IInitializeWithItem` interfaces.

Comment: Hmm. `IPropertyStore` is defined in ShlObj.pas, but I can't find any of the others anywhere.